# How to turn amazon ec2's status to failed

Tags: amazon-ec2

i'm want to change ec2 instance status to failed to test status check alarm is working. Also i wanted to it should be easily repaired after that. Because i thought changing network setting will do the job but after that cannot repair it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is the simple way todo this.

Login to ec2 with ssh and disables ethernet card by following:

```
sudo ifdown eth0
```

and wait until recieve alarm notification.

After that you can restart instance from aws console.

Comment: Thank  you - this fails the "Instance Status Checks" - is there a way we try to trigger "System Status Checks" ?